# FooterView in ListView not found using Espresso

Tags: android, listview, android-espresso

I am writing an espresso test which checks which fails to find a TextView within a FooterView that i added programmatically to a ListView.The only way to find that TextView in the espresso test, is to wait for 1 second before checking if this TextView exists.

```
    // checks if the list view contains an issue that has the text "Do" somewhere
    onView(withId(R.id.listView)).check(matches(hasDescendant(withText(containsString("Do")))));
    // swipes down to access the load older issues button
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.mainLayout))).perform(swipeUp());

    // View listView = shelfActivity.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView_footer_textview); // returns the view, even when espresso tells that it does not exist
    // Thread.sleep(1000); // need to wait in order to find the footerview of the list view

    // check if the load older issues button is here
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.listView_footer_textview), isDisplayed())).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

This TextView inside the FooterView is actually existing, and i can find it inside the test on the same place, if i try to get it with the normal findById() method, but dont find it when i check it with espresso.

So my question is:
Do i really have to call Thread.sleep(1000) to pass the test if i want to check for a TextView inside a FooterView. For me the great advantage of espresso is, that i do not have to deal with waiting until a view is ready, so is there no espresso feature existing that is doing that automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can find FooterView of `ListView` by `onData` method.

Here is [official documents](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/advanced/#matching-a-view-that-is-a-footerheader-in-a-listview).

> For example:
>
> ```
> public static final String FOOTER = "FOOTER";
> ...
> View footerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, listView, false);
> ((TextView) footerView.findViewById(R.id.item_content)).setText("count:");
> ((TextView) footerView.findViewById(R.id.item_size)).setText(String.valueOf(data.size()));
> listView.addFooterView(footerView, FOOTER, true);
> ```
>
> Then, you can write a matcher that matches this object:
>
> ```
> import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;
> import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.instanceOf;
> import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
>
> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
> public static Matcher<Object> isFooter() {
>   return allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is(LongListActivity.FOOTER));
> }
> ```
>
> And loading the view in a test is trivial:
>
> ```
> import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.Espresso.onData;
> import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
> import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.sample.LongListMatchers.isFooter;
>
> public void testClickFooter() {
>   onData(isFooter())
>     .perform(click());
>   ...
> }
> ```

Comment: it is not the problems that i never find the textview inside my footer view, the problem is that i only find it after i let the tread sleep at least for 1 second. the same problem remains, if i add the is(LongListActivity.FOOTER) criteria to my search (what's actually not necessary as searching for the id should be enough).

as mentioned above this problem also does not occur when i search for the same textview with  shelfActivity.getActivity().findViewById(); in that case i find the expected textview immediately, without the need to sleep for 1 second.

Comment: I can't understand the problem, since `but fails to find a FooterView` in question, and `never find the textview inside my footer view` in above comment. `R.id.listView_footer` is id of TextView ?

Comment: sorry, the description was not so clear, i edited it now. it fails to find a textview inside a footer view, if i dont call sleep(1000) before the check.